# No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0+cu111

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, python-3.8, requirements.txt

I am trying to install [Codegen](https://github.com/salesforce/CodeGen) in my machine.

At the time of installing using `virtualenv`, I am getting the following error:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.9.0+cu111 (from versions: 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0+cu111
```

I have also tried to install the libraries using `conda`. With `conda`, I am getting the following error:

```
CondaValueError: could not parse '--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html' in: requirements.txt
```

```
> cat requirements.txt
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.9.0+cu111
transformers==4.16.2%
```

Comment: same problem with pytorch

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem when I install a wheel.

I solved it by changing the .whl file

In xxxx.whl/xxxxx.dist-info/METADATA

```
Requires-Dist: torch (==1.9.1+cu111)
Requires-Dist: torchvision (==0.10.1+cu111)
```

delete '+cu111':

```
Requires-Dist: torch (==1.9.1)
Requires-Dist: torchvision (==0.10.1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).